# Cannot update or install any new software in any version of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've read the other posts about being unable to install software in eclipse, but I still can't seem to get anything to work. I've tried on both Eclipse Indigo and Eclipse Juno - neither of which seem to be able to connect to anything, yet I can open the web browser.

On my other computer, which was previously configured, it contacts the software sites perfectly fine. I can also use the internal web browser on both version of eclipse - navigating to `www.google.com`.

I've tried updating Eclipse using `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/` and I have tried to install ADT with `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`.

I'm attaching an image of the error I'm getting. **Also it appears I am getting 'permission denied'**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the ADT, i couldnt get it to work with indigo for the life of me. After looking around a lot i realized that there are some comparability restrictions for the ADT plug in. The latest version of the ADT works on Eclipse Helios 3.6 or higher.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

also make sure to do "run as administrator" when you start eclipse if you are going to install software.

Comment: It's not just ADT. Also, that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I had a permission denied error when installing updates on eclipse, and running as administrator got rid of the error for me, sorry it wasn't of any help to you

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I'm not sure if it would help but here is what I did anyway:

1. Uninstalled AVG
2. Ran SFC /scannow
3. SFC found some corrupted windows files and repaired them
4. Restart

Not sure if uninstalling AVG did anything, but I saw it as a possible solution somewhere else.

I am now using MSE since it seems to be more compatible with my system...

Comment: Thanks for your tip! It was the f**** AVG. I was trying for hours. I just disabled it, not uninstalled, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to connect thru a proxy?
Check you browsers connections settings.

Comment: I am not using any proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before and it turned out to be due to a VPN connection I had open. It must have been trying to go via that, although no other applications have had that problem. So perhaps check that you don't have any static routes which are interfering.

Comment: can you explain how to do that?